# Experiments to show that a voltmeter measures energy per unit charge

Tags: electricity, experimental-physics, specific-reference, experimental-technique

In "[Physics for the Inquiring Mind](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691151151/physics-for-the-inquiring-mind)" by Eric Rogers, an experiment is described to show that a voltmeter (considered as a black box) indeed measures work done per unit charge by measuring the latter directly and comparing it with the voltmeter reading: He considers a resistor inside of a calorimeter, and then calculates from the temperature increase the transferred energy etc. and then compare the results to the voltmeter reading.

[image]

Later he writes:

> Some people like to use the voltmeter experiment with coil in water to
> "measure the me­chanical equivalent of heat," as further
> testimony in favor of Joule's work and the great generalization of the conservation of energy. In that case they cannot also use this experiment to test the voltmeter.

Are there other experiments with the same purpose, in particular ones that doesn't use the theory of heat? Do you have references to papers where it is described of how those experiments are actually carried out in detail.

In a footnote he suggests an approach as follows:

> One, an ultimate court of, appeal in electrodynamics, consists of
> making a very primitive generator whose voltage can be calculated
> directly from its dimensions and its speed of running and a measured
> current which is used to produce a magnetic field. This will provide a
> standard voltage.

Do you have references to such an experiment actually carried out?